# Generating list of known fusions for Arriba from COSMIC

Tags: rna-seq, fusions

The RNA-Seq fusion detection program [Arriba](https://github.com/suhrig/arriba) features the ability to white-list known gene fusions, specifically the authors recommend using [COSMIC](https://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cosmic/download?genome=37) as a source of these [here](http://arriba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/input-files/#known-fusions). Specifically they state:

> A comprehensive list of known fusions can be obtained from CancerGeneCensus in the section titled "Complete Fusion Export". *Depending on the gene annotation that is used to run arriba, some gene names need to be adjusted*.

Emphasis is mine to highlight the issue here!

The state the format of the input file they require to be:

> The file has two columns separated by a tab. Each line lists a pair of
>   genes. The order of the genes is irrelevant. arriba searches for both
>   genes as the 5' end and the 3' end of a fusion. Lines starting with a
>   hash (#) are treated as comments. Optionally, the file can be
>   gzip-compressed.

However the format of the download from COSMIC is somewhat different:

```
Sample ID       Sample name     Primary site    Site subtype 1  Site subtype 2  Site subtype 3  Primary histology       Histology subtype 1     Histology subtype 2     Histology subtype 3     Fusion ID       Translocation Name      Fusion Type     PUBMED_PMID     ID_STUDY
WWWWWWW WWWWWWW thyroid NS      NS      NS      carcinoma       papillary_carcinoma     follicular_variant      NS                              16784981
WWWWWWW WWWWWWW thyroid NS      NS      NS      carcinoma       papillary_carcinoma     follicular_variant      NS      1271    CCDC6{ENST00000263102}:r.1_535_RET{ENST00000355710}:r.2369_5659 Observed mRNA   16784981
WWWWWWW WWWWWWW thyroid NS      NS      NS      carcinoma       papillary_carcinoma     follicular_variant      NS      1272    CCDC6{ENST00000263102}:r.1_535_RET{ENST00000355710}:r.2369_5659 Inferred Breakpoint     16784981
XXXXXXX XXXXXXX thyroid NS      NS      NS      carcinoma       papillary_carcinoma     follicular_variant      NS                              16784981
YYYYYYY YYYYYYY thyroid NS      NS      NS      carcinoma       papillary_carcinoma     follicular_variant      NS                              16728576
YYYYYYY YYYYYYY thyroid NS      NS      NS      carcinoma       papillary_carcinoma     follicular_variant      NS      1216    PAX8{NM_003466.2}:r.?_PPARG{NM_015869.2}:r.?    Inferred Breakpoint     16728576
```

*Note: numeric samples IDs have been deliberately replaced with letters here.*

Using this file, as is, will cause arriba to spurt out many warnings that the gene names in the first two columns are not recognised:

`WARNING: unknown gene in known fusions list: XXXXXXX`

From the looks of the rest of my arriba output the currency of gene IDs its using would appear to be gene symbols taken from the `gencode.gft` I'm supplying it.

I'm thus assuming the format arriba requires for a known gene list to be:

```
SYMB1   SYMB2
SYMB3   SYMB4
```

Where the record separator is a tab character `\t`

My question is how can I reprocess the COSMIC "Complete Fusion Export" [`.tsv` file](https://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cosmic/download?genome=37) to the format required for arriba to act as a white-list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this with a one-liner:

```
grep -v 'Sample ID' CosmicFusionExport.tsv | cut -f 12 | grep -v -e '^$' | perl -lne '/^(\S+?)\{\S+\d+}\S+_(\S+?)\{/; print "$1\t$2"' | sort -u > CosmicFusionList.tsv
```

The various parts of the piped command are as follows:

1. Remove header:`grep -v 'Sample ID' CosmicFusionExport.tsv |`
2. Extract 12th field (Translocation Name):`cut -f 12 |`
3. Remove blank entries:`grep -v -e '^$' |`
4. Extract gene symbols from 12th column:`perl -lne '/^(\S+?)\{\S+\d+}\S+_(\S+?)\{/; print "$1\t$2"' |`
5. Remove duplicate lines:`sort -u > CosmicFusionList.tsv`
6. Optionally the final two stages could be:`sort -u | gzip -c > CosmicFusionList.tsv.gz` to make use of file compression (for what it's worth on a 3.9 kB file)

Since the authors of arriba have neglected to document this necessary data munging step, I've posted it here in Q and A format in the hope that it will be useful to others, and other solutions can be proposed.